# How to install multiple python and pip versions on linux

Tags: python, virtualenv, pyenv, asdf-vm

I'm trying to install multiple python versions in linux, but `asdf` or `pyenv` get stuck with an error:

```
ERROR: The Python ssl extension was not compiled. Missing the OpenSSL lib?
```

`apt install libssl` or `apt install libssl1.0` didn't solved...

I already have version 2.7 and 3.8 by default.

Then I've stalled version 3.4 by downloading its source and building manually. If i try to create a virtual environment like `python3.4 -m venv myenv`, i can activate `python --version` shows the correct one:

```
$ python --version                             
Python 3.4.0
```

but pip still referenced to python 3.8:

```
(myenv)$ pip --version                                  
pip 21.0.1 from ~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/ only has README file, and i can't figure out how to properly set this

Comment: What is the output of `which pip` and `echo $PATH` when your 3.4 virtual env is activated?

Comment: why not use `python3.4 -m pip --version`...?

Comment: install python as per instructions then in bashrc give alias to each python version you want to use

Comment: i tryied:
```python3.4 -m pip install wheel```
```/usr/local/bin/python3.4: No module named pip```

Comment: PIP
```$ which pip```
```pip: aliased to pip3```
PIP3
```$ which pip3```
```/usr/local/bin/pip3```
PATH
```echo $PATH```
```home/paulo/.asdf/shims:/home/paulo/.asdf/bin:/home/paulo/.nvm/versions/node/v10.19.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin```

Comment: conda (miniconda) is another option, might be suitable depending on how you want to use Python.

Comment: i couldn't figure it out so I updated the project to python3.8

Comment: Don't you have to install pip first for python 3.4.0?